# Error replacing network map and notary on corda

Tags: corda

we have replaced our network map and one of our three notaries with new machine.
We stopped all nodes. Changed configuration in node.conf files to point to new notary and network map but after start all network environment is broke and we are not able to submit any transaction between nodes.

We see following errors:
1- In the New Newtwork Map

> [ERROR] 2018-04-18T09:30:30,588Z [Thread-12
>   (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@2f07930a)]
>   core.client.createConnection - AMQ214016: Failed to create netty
>   connection javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out    at
>   io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source)
>   ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final] [WARN ]
>   2018-04-18T09:30:46,087Z [Thread-11
>   (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@2f07930a)]
>   core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected:
>   AMQ119014: Did not receive data from null within the 60,000ms
>   connection TTL. The connection will now be closed.
>   [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]

2- In one previous existing notary node:

> [ERROR] 2018-04-18T10:22:05,682Z [main]
>   internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure -
>   HHH000346: Error during managed flush
>   [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement] [ERROR] 2018-04-18T10:22:05,714Z [main]
>   internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1434)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.updateInfoDB(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:287)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.access$updateInfoDB(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:52)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache$addNode$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$2.invoke(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:169)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache$addNode$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$2.invoke(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:52)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:84)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:75)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:65)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:168)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.registerWithNetworkMapIfConfigured(AbstractNode.kt:512)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:221)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:312)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:95)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:74)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:11)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?] Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1323)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:80)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     ... 22 more Caused by:
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation:
>   "UK_MH4X07LLMH7CQIHD64UPRW7TT_INDEX_2 ON
>   PUBLIC.""NODE_INFOS_NODEINFOSCHEMAV1$DBHOSTANDPORT""(ADDRESSES_HOST,
>   ADDRESSES_PORT) VALUES ('10.83.80.46', 10002, 48)"; SQL statement:
>   insert into node_infos_NodeInfoSchemaV1$DBHostAndPort
>   (NodeInfoSchemaV1$PersistentNodeInfo_node_info_id, addresses_host,
>   addresses_port) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-194]  at
>   org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:629)
>   ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]     at
>   org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:203)
>   ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
>   ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
>   ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
>   ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
>   ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1323)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:80)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]

3- error on existing corda node:

> [ERROR] 2018-04-18T08:50:39,726Z [Node thread]
>   network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.invoke - Exception processing update
>   from network map service javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1434)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.updateInfoDB(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:287)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.access$updateInfoDB(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:52)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache$addNode$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.invoke(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:164)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache$addNode$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.invoke(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:52)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:72)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:65)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:163)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.processRegistration(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:223)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.processUpdatePush(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:206)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache$addMapService$1.invoke(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:137)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache$addMapService$1.invoke(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:52)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient.callHandlers(NodeMessagingClient.kt:444)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient.access$callHandlers(NodeMessagingClient.kt:76)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:429)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:76)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:84)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:75)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:65)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:421)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:76)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$fetchFrom$1.get(AffinityExecutor.kt:44)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_162]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_162]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_162]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_162]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_162]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_162]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_162]     at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?] Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1323)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     ... 37 more Caused by:
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation:
>   "UK_MH4X07LLMH7CQIHD64UPRW7TT_INDEX_2 ON
>   PUBLIC.""NODE_INFOS_NODEINFOSCHEMAV1$DBHOSTANDPORT""(ADDRESSES_HOST,
>   ADDRESSES_PORT) VALUES ('10.83.80.5', 10001, 34)"; SQL statement:
>   insert into node_infos_NodeInfoSchemaV1$DBHostAndPort
>   (NodeInfoSchemaV1$PersistentNodeInfo_node_info_id, addresses_host,
>   addresses_port) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-194]  at
>   org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:629)
>   ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]     at
>   org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:203)
>   ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
>   ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
>   ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
>   ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
>   ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1323)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]     ... 37 more [WARN ]
>   2018-04-18T08:51:17,425Z [Thread-1
>   (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@319aa9ee)]
>   core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected:
>   AMQ119014: Did not receive data from null within the 60,000ms
>   connection TTL. The connection will now be closed.
>   [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]

is there a way to clean network / notaries to work with new scenario?

Thanks!!

Javier

Comment: not entirely sure here what is happening at bootstrapping.It's saying the host and port already exists. if this is in dev ENV. why don't you just try and delete the data from the specific tables and try to start the nodes?. my guess is at the time of detecting the change in the node.config file it's reloading everything. It's a long shot.

Comment: Hi,  have tried to delete values in these tables but now I have this error in all nodes:
ERROR] 2018-04-19T12:07:22,287Z [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup
rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: List is empty.
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Network bootstrapper to load out your network with the new conf file. Please take a look at: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-bootstrapper.html

In related to your original question, you can achieve the notary sway by follow the steps for: *Adding a new node to the network* section because it is virtually the same process: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-bootstrapper.html#adding-a-new-node-to-the-network